# SwiftData Model not updating values provided in init

Tags: ios, swift, caching, swift-data

I'm attempting to maintain a local copy of server data in my application and thought I could accomplish this with [swift-data](/questions/tagged/swift-data) (in fact, [I've followed this article about it in the official Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftdata/maintaining-a-local-copy-of-server-data)). However, **SwiftData ignores the values set in the `@Model` initializer and any subsequent attempts to update the values**.

My impression was that: by using the `@Attribute(.unique)` value on the `id` parameter, any time I created a model with *the same ID as an existing one*, SwiftData would *update the existing model*. That doesn't appear to be the case.

I can't quite determine *why* SwiftData is not allowing me to update my model (esp. from inside the model's own initializer). Is this a bug? Some undocumented behavior? Or have I just got things configured incorrectly, or am using these models in an unsupported way?

---

This behavior can be replicated using a simple model object and initializer like this:

```swift
@Model
final class Item {
    
    @Attribute(.unique)
    var id: String
    
    var timestamp: Date
    
    var deleted: Bool
    
    // Initializes a local SwiftData model from a "RemoteItem", which is just a Codable
    // object generated from a server response.
    //
    init?(from remoteModel: RemoteItem) {
        guard let remoteId = remoteModel.id else { return nil }
        self.id = remoteId
        self.timestamp = remoteModel.timestamp
        
        print("Initialized Item model with deletion value from remote model: \(remoteModel.deleted)")
        // Prints correct value of deleted to the console (e.g. true)

        self.deleted = remoteModel.deleted
        
        print("Initialized Item model with remote deletion. Value is now: \(self.deleted)")
        // Prints INCORRECT value of deleted to the console (e.g. false)
    }
    
}
```

Then, in a data source actor (or other similar class):

```swift
func fetchItems() async throws -> [Item] {
    let someRemoteItems = try await networkRequestForRemoteItems()
        
    // Map the remote items to locally cached items, similar to the demo
    // provided by Apple here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftdata/maintaining-a-local-copy-of-server-data
    let localItemCopies: [Item] = someRemoteItems.compactMap({ Item(from: $0) })
    
    // "Cache" the remote items
    for localItem in localItemCopies {
        await cacheContainer.insert(localItem)
    }

    return localItemCopies
}
```

As noted above, any items that already existed locally in the SwiftData model store are not updated when inserted again here. And for additional context, I've seen other questions asking about similar behavior **but only in the context of SwiftUI**, which is not relevant here.

Comment: Maybe the problem is with cacheContainer, what is that?

Comment: I think, the Apple example is more for illustration how to use SwiftData. Have you considered to utilise URLCache? This IMHO is the preferred way to cache HTTP responses.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't replicate your problem exactly but I did get my code to crash so I am going to post my solution for that crash because I believe it's the same underlying problem.

The `PersistentModel` protocol (that all `@Model` classes conforms to) extends `Identifiable` which means it comes with an `id` property and the type for that property is `PersistentIdentifier`.

By creating your own id property you override the default behaviour and I am pretty sure this is the reason why your code isn't working, I don't know whether this is a bug in SwiftData or something not properly documented but personally I never add an `id` property to my `@Model` classes.

So what resolved my crash and what I recommend is to rename the id property to something else to not interfere with SwiftData's internal identification of objects.

```
@Model
final class Item {
    @Attribute(.unique)
    var remoteId: String
    //...
}
```

As mentioned this solved my crash and I could see the existing objects being updated rather than new ones being inserted in my List view.